# How can I get the Comment's replies in Facebook SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fbsdk

I am working on integrating the Facebook SDK. I need to get the replies of the comments in the picture.

I am able to get the comments with the id's, but I am not able to get the replies of the comment.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/comment

Any help, is much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/comment#edges, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/object/comments

Answer (score 1):

You can get replies for each comment by using comments' id like:

```
/comment_id/comments?access_token=ABC.....123
```

**comment_id** = `<POST_ID>_<COMMENT_ID>`

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch replies with the same endpoint

```
/object-id/comments - object id is an id of comment replies foer you want
```

also you can fetch comments with replies in one request

```
post-id/comments?fields=id,message... [other fields you want] ...,comments{from,message,id... }
```